# Visual Studio XML Editor doesn't re-validate after schema changes

Tags: xml, visual-studio, validation

I'm trying to fix my schema file so it matches the output document... the document will auto-validate once, but VS is caching the schema, so when I update the schema, VS won't go look at it again. I have to close down Visual Studio and re-start it, then it will validate the document (one time, grrr) against the new schema file. How can I force it to go get the schema file again after I upload it to the web server???

I have to use Visual Studio 2005 (or 2008). I know there's better XML editors out there.

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio. Once you've reported it, edit your question to include the URL of your bug report. That way, others on SO can vote on how important we feel this bug is.

Comment: I don't think they care any more, it is a problem with VS 2005. I don't even see a place to submit a bug for that version.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-completion file often gives me trouble in Visual Studios especially in large projects. I find if you delete the auto-complete cache it will re-validate without having the need to shut-down. In C++ the file is *.ncb. If you look for the cache in the solution folder and delete it, it should re-validate without the need to restart.